# Автоматизированная установка web service под IIS

Tags: iis

Интересует вопрос автоматизации создания web-сервиса под iis с помощью скрипта или какого-либо установщика.
У нас тупая служба эксплуатации и в инструкции из 20 пунктов они каждый раз умудряются делать по несколько ошибок, в результате каждый раз разработчикам приходится разбираться в их косяках.
Каким образом можно автоматизировать процесс установки web-сервиса?
Сервис написан под .NET, в настоящий момент только вижу переход на WS под другие сервера приложения, например tomcat или websphere.

Answer (score 2):

В студии на веб-проекте есть кнопка Publish. Которая умеет собирать Wed Deploy Package. На выходе получется zip + cmd для его установки.

Допишите к нему снаружи свой cmd, для спуска имени сервера и имени/пароля. Включите [Web Deploy на сервере](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) и забуьте про 20 пунктов как про страшный сон.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня не был установлен Web Deployment в VS 2008, буду копать в этом направлении!